# Connecting VM Client To Server On My Computer C#

Tags: c#, server, client, tcplistener

I'm having trouble with this network chat application code I found. It works fine when both applications are run on the same computer, but when trying to connect a VM client to my host app running on my real install, I get a timeout. Here is the code.

````
static readonly object _lock = new object();
        static readonly Dictionary<int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary<int, TcpClient>();

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int count = 1;

            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.59"), 5000);
            ServerSocket.Start();

            while(true) {
                TcpClient client = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                lock(_lock) list_clients.Add(count, client);
                Console.WriteLine("Someone connected!!");

                Thread t = new Thread(handle_clients);
                t.Start(count);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

class Client {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.59");
            int port = 5000;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("client connected!!");
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            Thread thread = new Thread(o => ReceiveData((TcpClient)o));

            thread.Start(client);

            string s;
            while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((s = Console.ReadLine()))) {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            thread.Join();
            ns.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("disconnect from server!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM is probably running in a different network interface.

Try instead:

`TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);`

This way you tell the server to listen on any network interface.

Addition: Also, the VM client should connect to the IP address your computer (with TCPListener program) has, within the VM network range. Not 192.168.1.59, but:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("172.17.xx.xx");
    ...
```

Comment: Just tried this and it still timed out. IPConfig is showing that the VM is 172.17.158.37, so I think you may be right about the network range. What is up with this exactly?

Comment: The VM client should connect to the IP address your computer (with TCPListener program) has, within the VM network range. This will be in the line of 172.17 ... and not 192.168.1.59

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly. What needs to be changed?

Comment: The client code: 
        `static void Main(string[] args) {
           IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("172.17.xx.xx");`

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. Is there any way I could configure Hyper-V to not do this? To my knowledge, on the server I run the IPs were assigned like normal.

Comment: Found out what was wrong. Hyper-V's Default Switch was the culprit. Using my actual hardware as an external switch got me on to the LAN with a proper IP.